# Syntax highlighting in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

For some reason my syntax error highlighting has disappeared from Visual Studio 2010. For example, this shows no error until I try to build this...

String userName = Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER");

fW4YQHKRHAENKR!!!;

Comment: You are not talking about syntax highlighting, that should produce the error 'squiggles'.  Red zigzag line underneath the bad code.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075.aspx

**Edit**
As per comment, I've added the text from the link:

How to: Reset Your Settings
Visual Studio 2010 Other Versions 19 out of 25 rated this helpful - Rate this topic
You can reset the integrated development environment (IDE) to a previous state using the Import and Export Settings wizard. All settings and categories are applied by default; if you want to specify which settings to change, use the option Import selected environment settings. For more information, see How to: Share Settings Between Computers or Visual Studio Versions.

To reset your settings

On the Tools menu, click Import and Export Settings.

On the Welcome to the Import and Export Settings Wizard page, click Reset all settings and then click Next.

If you want to save your current settings combination, click Yes, save my current settings, specify a file name, and then click Next.

—or—

If you want to delete your current settings combination, choose No, just reset settings, overwriting my current settings, and then click Next. This option does not delete default settings, which will still be available the next time you use the wizard.

In Which collection of settings do you want to reset to, select a settings collection from the list.

Click Finish.

The Reset Complete page alerts you to any problems encountered during the reset.

Comment: No... Not like that. Don't just copy/paste it all here, **summarize**.

Answer (score -1):

did you install any plugin/addin to the visual studio recently? A malfunctioning plugin or addon could be the cause  of this problem.

Comment: Ah, same thing happened to me.. just installed ReSharper and VS10x plugin and my error syntax is no longer wonder... ie cod elike `RowKey = string.Format("{0}_{1}", DateScheduled.Ticks, shjkfh mbox,sbyte fs=decimal skdj fasifh aiow 5u23);` doesnt highlight ~ WTF